# Blockchain.com wallet

Tags: blockchain

Just a basic/general question, recently when I send bitcoin using blockchain.com's wallet I noticed within my transaction logs Received BTC to: BTC Trading Wallet. From: BTC Wallet directly after Sent BTC To: ....... I'm just wondering why this is occurring and what exactly is BTC Trading Wallet and why my funds are being sent to BTC Trading Wallet?

It almost appears as a duplicate transaction but to my " own address "?